# Accelerometer and sensorevent

Tags: android

I seem to be really bad at physics (
I don't understand how do an Accelerometer work...

How [Sensor Event](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

The documantation says

When the device lies flat on a table, the acceleration value is +9.81, which correspond to the acceleration of the device (0 m/s^2) minus the force of gravity (-9.81 m/s^2).

But its velocity is stable and equals 0...Then the acceleration is zero.

Answer (score 1):

First off, 0 velocity doesn't mean 0 acceleration.  Acceleration is the first derivative of velocity-  its the change in velocity.  So an item that hits a wall has 0 velocity (the wall stops it) but can have a large acceleration (from its speed to 0).

9.8m/s^2 of acceleration (approxiamtely, depending on elevation and sensor noise) is correct-  9.8 is the force of gravity pulling you to the center of the earth.  Everything on this planet experiences 9.8m/s^2 constantly downwards to the center of the earth.  But we have 0 velocity downwards because the planet is solid and stops us.

Comment: Thanks for your unswer, but I still don't get it...U need to change the velocity to have some acceleration. If the phone is simply lying on a table it's not moving... His velocity is stable, it doesn't change and therefore the acceleration of the device is 0... If I dropped down a phone then it had 9.8 m/s^2 acceleration... Sorry for dumb questions(

Comment: You are changing the velocity, constantly.  Its just always being stopped.  Gravity is always pulling you down.

Comment: I was trying to keep a simple lay explanation, but here's more physics.  Accelerations are caused by forces.  The net acceleration of an object is proportinal to the sum of all forces on the object, F=ma.  Gravity constantly asserts a force on an object equal to 9.8 m/s^2.  There are no other forces on the object, so it experiences an acceleration equal to 9.8m/s^2 towards the earth.  If you want an answer to why it isn't achieving a velocity then we can talk about normal forces between the table and the object.  But at that point you ought to just take a physics course.

Comment: Well,I do really wish)
How this cource is called?
Mechanics or smth more precize?)

Comment: Mechanics.  It will go over the basics of Forces, motion, and interactions.  If you just want an overview a version without calculus will teach you the basics well enough to understand this type of thing.